# How to enable more than one command

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm fairly new to this format of discord.py and I can't seem to get two commands to work.
For example, I have the command; 'hello' and the command 'valid'. Whenever I activate the bot, it only responds to either 'valid' or 'hello', never both. 
Is there some way to fix this?

I've tried very little as this problem is very new to me and I have no idea how to tackle it.

Here's the code that I've used for commands:

```
 @client.event

 async def on_message(message):

     if message.content.startswith('!hello'):

         messages= ["*tips hat* G'day ", "Yeehaw pardner,  ", "Howdy, ", "Gutentag! "]

         await client.send_message(message.channel, random.choice(messages) + message.author.mention)


 @client.event

 async def on_message(message):

     if message.content.startswith('!valid'):

         rannum = random.randint(0, 100)

         await client.send_message(message.channel, (message.author.mention + " is",rannum,"% valid!"))


     client.run(TOKEN)
```

No error messages show up when this happens. I will appreciate any help possible in this situation!

Comment: You need to combine them into a single `on_message` event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what @Patrick Haugh mentioned, you can only have 1 of `on_message` event.
Plus, you probably only need one of that event.
 Since `on_message` defines a event that occurs when you recieve a message from someone. You can just check what the message's content is and do actions based on that.

Like so:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content.startswith('!valid'):
        rannum = random.randint(0, 100)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, (message.author.mention + " is",rannum,"% valid!"))
    elif message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        messages= ["*tips hat* G'day ", "Yeehaw pardner,  ", "Howdy, ", "Gutentag! "]
        await client.send_message(message.channel, random.choice(messages) + message.author.mention)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry if the question seemed dumb, this format is something I'm new to.